# Not expected result in WHERE condition

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, encoding, where-clause

I run the similar queries, but get difference

When run these

```
select * from source_aliases where source_alias = 'store'
select * from source_aliases where lower(source_alias) = lower('store')
select * from source_aliases where source_alias like 'store'
```

there is no result

but when run these one

```
select * from source_aliases where source_alias like '%store%'
select * from source_aliases where upper(source_alias) = upper('store')
select * from source_aliases where source_alias ilike 'store'
select * from source_aliases where convert_to(source_alias, 'UTF8')  = 'store'
```

I can get the row

The params:
PostgreSQL 10.23, utf8

Why the

```
select * from source_aliases where source_alias = 'store'
```

doesn't work

Comment: `source_alias like 'store'` is identical to `source_alias = 'store'` as there are no wildcards. As for why `lower` produces different results from `upper`, that's because some collations (ie languages) *do* have different upper- and lower-case representations. The [Turkish (dotless) I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotless_I) is a common example - `I` can be lowercased to either `i` or `ı`. Uppercasing `i` would produce `İ`.  `ilike` is case-*in*sensitive and would match all 4 `i`s

Comment: To handle such cases use a case-*in*sensitive collation for that field

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think the solutions might be !!!

1. Case sensitivity: Depending on the database configuration, the comparison operator `=` might be case sensitive. If the value of `source_alias` in the `source_aliases` table is stored as `'Store'`, for example, then the query `select * from source_aliases where source_alias = 'store'` will not match any rows because of the case difference.
2. Leading/trailing spaces: If there are leading or trailing spaces in the value of `source_alias`, then the query `select * from source_aliases where source_alias = 'store'` will not match any rows. In this case, using the like operator with wildcards, such as `select * from source_aliases where source_alias like '%store%'`, will match any rows where 'store' appears anywhere in the value of `source_alias`.
3. Data type mismatch: If the data type of the `source_alias` column is not a string type, then the query `select * from source_aliases where source_alias = 'store'` will not match any rows. In this case, using a type conversion function, such as `convert_to(source_alias, 'UTF8')`, can help ensure that the data types match before doing the comparison.